# How to theme the emails send through SMTP module?

Tags: 7, emails, theming

Drupal7 website send email  using the SMTP module.

I have to theme the email template with my website default theme logo,header and  footer links.

How could I achieve this one?

Referred this [Using HTML Mail together with SMTP Authentication Support](https://www.drupal.org/node/1200142)
 and configured modules **HTML Mail** and **Mail System**

Added template ***htmlmail--smtp.tpl.php*** with content from this [link](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/htmlmail/plain/htmlmail.tpl.php?id=refs/heads/7.x-2.x) 
in my custom theme folder.

While sending **htmlmail test mail** the template contents are rendered.

Also **SMTP test mail**  renders the template contents but other mails sent via **SMTP** module don't take this template.

Other mails include the registration mail,reset password, all other **system mails and all mails defined from custom modules**